# How do I format psych factor analysis output to tables?

Tags: r, psych

Has something changed with the `psych` package? There used to be a function `fa2latex` that let you produce latex code for factor analysis results, but I do not see it here (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/psych.pdf) . `df2latex` is there, but not `fa2latex`.

This is along the lines of what I need, but I am certain there are much better ways to accomplish this.

```
library(psych)
library(flextable)
#Make PCA model
data("Thurstone")
Thurstone
pca1<-principal(Thurstone, nfactors=2, rotate="varimax")
#Make function to save the object as word or html
psychSave<-function(x, cut=0.3, row.names=T, format="html", path){
  #Get the number of items in the pca
  n_items<-dim(x$loadings)[1]
  #Now sort 
  x_sorted<-fa.sort(x$loadings[1:n_items,])
  #Convert to data frame
  x_sorted<-data.frame(x_sorted)
  #Implement the cut option, converting all else to NA
  x_sorted<-apply(x_sorted, 2, function(z) {
    ifelse(abs(z)< cut, NA, z)
  })
  x_sorted<-data.frame(x_sorted)
  #Add Row Names in Variable Name
  x_sorted$Name<-rownames(x_sorted)
#Convert to flextable
  x_sorted<-flextable(x_sorted)
if(format=="html") {
  save_as_html(x_sorted, path=path)
}
else {
  save_as_docx(x_sorted, path=path)
}
}
#Save out. 
psychSave(pca1, format="html", path="~/Desktop/test.html")
```

I would like to add functionality here like have the item names printed in the table (first in the order of the columns) and add some of the summary statistics (e.g. communality).  I'll get to it, I guess, but there must be a way that someone has implemented some of this.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psychTools/psychTools.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be more explicit, the tth package will convert the latex output from fa2latx to an html document.

Thus

```
. library(tth)
library(psych)
f3 <- fa(Thurstone,3)
f3.lat <- fa2latex(f3)
f3.htm <- tth(f3.lat)
print(as.data.frame(f3.htm),row.names=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

That function was moved to psychTools several years ago.  You need to install and activate it

library(psychTools).

Comment: Forgive my follow-up. What is the best way to then convert the latex output to an html file for viewing. I often produce my analysis in an R Script (not in an RMarkdown document) and it is helpful to me to spit out an html file.

Comment: There are a number of latex to html converters available.  Psych just offers the latex table output (fa2latex, df2latex, cor2latex, etc.

Comment: Forgive me dullness, but I can't find one that will produce an html table in the script flow. I tried Hmisc::html, pander, Any tips?

Comment: The tth package seems to have what you want.